# JSLint and lodash

Tags: jslint, lodash

i'm using JSLint.NET with lodash. Code like this

```
var first = _.first(myArray);
```

will return a *Unexpected dangling '_' in '_'* error.
How can I exclude this one from being checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [nomen](http://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-dangling-_-in-a).

```
/*jslint nomen:true */
var myArray = [],
    _ = {},
    first;

first = _.first(myArray);
```

I mean, obviously this assumes you've got a good declaration for `_` and `myArray` somewhere to take the place of the declarations I added, above.  A simple underscore is a pretty nasty variable name, but the code above validates on jslint.com.  Guessing you're using <strike>Underscore.js</strike> [Lodash](http://lodash.com/), as you mentioned, which means you're probably going to use the `global` tag instead.

```
/*jslint nomen:true */
/*globals _ */
var myArray = [],
    first;

first = _.first(myArray);
```